# convert code that uses mutable data into immutable

Tags: scala

I have the following code

```
def get_prices(portfolio: List[String], years: Range): List[List[Option[Double]]] = {
    var outerList = List[List[Option[Double]]]()
    for( j <- years) 
    {
        var innerList = List[Option[Double]]()
        for( i <- portfolio) 
            innerList ::= get_first_price(i, j) 

        outerList ::= innerList.reverse
    }
    outerList.reverse
}
```

and I need to only use val. I am not sure how I can go thruough a loop without using var. ( It is a sumb requirement I have been given ).

The code is trying to obtain all first prices for the stock symbols from a portfolio (list of strings) and for the given range of years. The inner lists are for the stock symbols and the outer list for the years.

How can I convert the given code to code that doesn't use any of the mutable data structures ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `.map`.  Without knowing knowing what `get_first_price()` does we can't help you too much, but doing something like this in your function is probably what you want:

```
years.map(y => {
  portfolio.map(p => {
    getFirstPrice(p, y)  
  })
})
```